# Firefox 18 breaks mootools 1.2.5 selector engine

Tags: firefox, mootools

Working jsfiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/CfJyd/

The problem only occurs in Firefox 18 that I know of.

The following html:

```
<div class="test">Test Div</div>
<div class="testIgnore">This should stay the same</div>
```

With this js:

```
window.addEvent('domready',function() {
    $$('.test').set('html','Only Test should update');
});
```

Results in this output:

```
Only Test should update
Only Test should update
```

Upgrading to Mootools 1.4.5 isn't an option at the moment because of lots of plugins that use 1.2.5, can anybody point me in the right direction on getting a fix?

Comment: you should mark your own anser as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found the answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mootools-users/W7MHwTFHYQ4/B4HcR951XQYJ

Add the following code anywhere in javascript - I added it just above mootools, and it works perfectly:

```
String.prototype.contains = function(string, separator){
    return (separator) ? (separator + this + separator).indexOf(separator + string + separator) > -1 : String(this).indexOf(string) > -1;
};
```

Comment: mootools 1.2.6 is now available, that also fixes this problem

Answer (score 4):

known bug. If I remember correctly, it's to do with the early introduction of the *proposed* ES harmony `String.prototype.contains` in Gecko, which has a different 2-nd argument to the one in 1.2.5

a quick workaround is to say do, `delete Sting.prototype.contains` before you load MooTools so it redefines it. Since 1.3, this has stopped being a protected prototype method and has been redefined properly. I think there may have been a bug raised on the repo by one of the FireFox guys some 6 months ago as it was imminently landing in FF 17...

See this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789036#c23

Even Brendan Eich was commenting on this and suggesting it may be disabled in 18.0.1 as it was adopted prematurely.

Answer (score 2):

More background information on this: [MooTools 1.2.x was broken by adding String.prototype.contains](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789036)

The solution is to use the workaround from the other comment or upgrade to MooTools 1.3 or 1.4