# Mootools 1.2 and Firefox $$ selecting too many elements

Tags: javascript, mootools1.2

**Browser must be firefox**

**Mootools version must be 1.2.x**

1. $$ selector returns too many elements *only in firefox*

http://jsfiddle.net/e77Xp/4/

**HTML**

```
<div class="only_trucks diagramz" id="diatruck">
    <div class="lf">lf</div>
    <div class="rf">rf</div>
    <div class="la">la</div>
    <div class="ra">ra</div>
    <div class="lrfo">lrfo</div>
    <div class="rrfo">rrfo</div>
    <div class="lrfi">lrfi</div>
    <div class="rrfi">rrfi</div>
    <div class="lrro">lrro</div>
    <div class="rrro">rrro</div>
    <div class="lrri">lrri</div>
    <div class="rrri">rrri</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
selected = $$('.rf');
alert(selected.length);
console.log(selected);
```

This should only return 1 result but returns multiple results. It seems to be matching other classes that have "rf" in them.

**Besides updating to the latest version of mootools or changing class names, does anyone have a good fix for this?**

Comment: Weird, even the literal form `$$('div[class=rf]')` has this behavior

Comment: Good question. The app is heavy in JS, and I don't want anything else to break because of a simple update.

Comment: I may end up just making these ids as they are not used elsewhere anyway.

Comment: Wow that is a sticky bug!  even this doesn't work: `$$('.rf').filter(function (item) { return item.hasClass('rf');});`

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267457/firefox-18-breaks-mootools-1-2-5-selector-engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bug but it can be fixed (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14272657/16959)).  Add this code to your JavaScript.

```
String.prototype.contains = function(string, separator){
    return (separator) ? (separator + this + separator).indexOf(separator + string + separator) > -1 : String(this).indexOf(string) > -1;
};
```

Here is a [fixed demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e77Xp/7/)